# Why is this decoding/encoding process giving a different buffer array?

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, cryptoapi, arraybuffer

I have the following represented as an ArrayBuffer:

`const encryptedMsg = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, messageUTF8)`

The byte length of this value is 28:

```
encryptedMsg
// ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 28 }
```

When I convert this into a Uint8Array then I get the following values:

```
const encryptedMsgArr = new Uint8Array(encryptedMsg)
// Uint8Array(28) [ 237, 243, 213, 127, 248, 55, 37, 237, 209, 21, … ]
```

I want to convert this into a UTF-8 cyphertext with a standard decoder and later revert that with a standard encoder:

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
```

When decoding it:

```
const cypherText = decoder.decode(encryptedMsgArr)
"���\u007f�7%��\u0015\u00113\u0012\u0016�۹o׀.:+=��\u0015\u0015"
```

But when I try to encode it back into a Uint8Array then it doesn't match up even though utf-8 encoding was specified for both.

In fact the above doesn't even look like it's utf-8, and the byte length does not match up either (now 46 instead of 28):

```
encoder.encode(cypherText)
// Uint8Array(46) [ 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 127, … ]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Goal**

To be able to export the cyphertext so it can be decrypted elsewhere at a later stage. If UTF-8 decoding of the ArrayBuffer doesn't work, the only other thing I can think of is to convert the AB into a stringified version of the array of integers and export that string, but I don't think that is a very sane methodology.

**Edit**

Actually, just declaring the encoder and decoder without utf-8 encoding fixes the issue, but @ornic has provided a nice base64 encoding/decoding function to use instead.

```
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
```

Comment: Not every sequence of bytes can be decoded as valid UTF-8.

Comment: What other encodings are suitable for this operation as the main goal is to be able to generate an exportable string/cyphertext

Comment: Base64 would probably work. I don't know if there's a way to do that from a typed array without writing your own code however.

Comment: Ah of course, base64. Thanks!

Comment: There is a library to store bytes in javascript strings (since they are UTF-16) with minimal overhead. Very handy to store bytes in localStorage, since its size is limited. 

http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the most common way is to decode your bytes to ASCII text, not UTF-8.

Something like that (all that code is from my current project, I found almost all of it there, on SoF):

```
var bufferToBase64 = function (buffer) {
            var s = '';
            var uintArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            uintArray.filter(function (v) { s += String.fromCharCode(v); return false; });
            return window.btoa(s);
        };

var bytes = function (text) {
            return new Uint8Array(
               atob(text)
                  .split('')
                  .map(function (c) {
                       return c.charCodeAt(0);
                   })
            );
}
```

And the example of usage:

```
test = new Uint8Array([1, 5, 167, 12])
> Uint8Array(4) [1, 5, 167, 12]
test2 = bufferToBase64(test)
> "AQWnDA=="
test3 = bytes(test2)
> Uint8Array(4) [1, 5, 167, 12]
```

Comment: I like this approach. Accepted. Thanks!

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(v)`: That could be effectively decoding using the ISO-8859-1 character encoding, not ASCII. It is reversible, as you have done, so it has that going for it.